# Why tags file increasing large and how to avoid this issue

Tags: vim, ctags

I use vim and ctags to work. Before I compile the code, my tags file only 788 MBs, but after compiling my tags file is 35 GBs or more. Why the tags file creasing so large? It's because the binary file? And how can I avoid this issue?

Below is my tags command:
ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --java-kinds=+l  --python-kinds=-i

Comment: and my my cscope command: which is fast and cscope.out is small

CSCOPE_DIR="$PWD/cscope"
 
if [ ! -d "$CSCOPE_DIR" ]; then
mkdir "$CSCOPE_DIR"
fi
 
echo "Finding files ..."
find "$PWD" -name '*.[ch]' \
-o -name '*.cpp' \
-o -name '*.cc' \
-o -name '*.hpp' \
-o -name '*.py' \
-o -name '*.java' \
> "$CSCOPE_DIR/cscope.files"
 
echo "Adding files to cscope db: $PWD/cscope.db ..."
cscope -b -i "$CSCOPE_DIR/cscope.files"
 
export CSCOPE_DB="$PWD/cscope.out"
echo "Exported CSCOPE_DB to: '$CSCOPE_DB'"

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I checked up the tags file and found that the tags included all the toolchain and bazel compiling out files. All the middle files are symbolic links. So I use --links=no to ignore these files which resolve my issue.